# Probability of Uniform Distribution and Y=-2ln x

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The continuous random variable X has a pdf f(x)= 1, $0<x<1$ , zero elsewhere. Let Y=-2 ln X. Find the distribution of Y, its mean and variance. My solution: The support of $Y$ is $(0,\infty) $  $P( -2$ ln $ X \lt y)$ = $P(ln X\lt \frac y{-2})$ how will I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cumulative distribution function of $Y$ is $$F_Y(y)= P(-2\ln(X)\leq y) = P(\ln(X)\geq -\frac{y}{2})=P(X\geq e^{-\frac{y}{2}})=1 - e^{-\frac{y}{2}}$$ if $y>0$ and zero otherwise. Now differentiate it and  get the pdf and then compute the mean and variance. Or if you recognize it is a exponential distribution with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$ and check some table for the mean and variance.